# Unity SSLStream AuthenticateAsClient gives SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm developing an application using Secure Sockets in Unity5 (in C#)  to allow a server to push information to clients.  I want to use Socket and SSLStream for this, to keep the communications secure.

I have an elastic beanstalk environment setup with a certificate provided by the AWS certificate service.

I've written a client class that can connect to this environment with a RemoteCertificateValidationCallback below:

```
 public static bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(System.Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    bool isOk = true;
    // If there are errors write them out
    if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        //Debug.Log(sslPolicyErrors.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(sslPolicyErrors.ToString());
        return false;
    }
    return isOk;
}
```

When I run this code from a Console application created in Visual Studio 2017 I get sslPolicyErrors.None as expected.

Running the exact same code from within Unity5 (minus Console references) gives me sslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable.

I've tried importing the certificates to the Mono trust store using mozroots -import --machine which gives the following output:

```
Issuer: C=US, O=Amazon, OU=Server CA 1B, CN=Amazon
Serial number: 66-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-46-xx-xx-xx-xx-0D
Valid from 05/05/2017 00:00:00 to 05/06/2018 12:00:00
```

I've been hunting around but can find nothing that would suggest why this works as a standalone console program, but not when run from Unity.  If I ignore this sslPolicyError specifically, everything works just fine, communication between the client and server happens as expected.  But I don't want to be randomly ignoring an error that could mean the communications could be compromised.

I'm really hoping someone here has some idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why this works as a standalone console program, but not when run from Unity?

As [Mono official said](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/), Mono doesn’t include root certificates while standalone program using system certs.

There is one solution that install the cert via `X509Store`.

```
string cert = "BASE64 ENCODED CERT(PEM), NOT HEADER AND FOOTER, BASICALLY EXPORTED BY OPENSSL";
byte[] certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cert);
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(cert);
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(certificate);
store.Close();
```

You can use `openssl` to export a pem, like `openssl x509 -inform DER -in YOUR_CER.cer -out YOUR_PEM.pem`.

Once the proper cert is installed, `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` won't return `RemoteCertificateNotAvailable` anymore if connecting to trusted sites.